# onActivityResult not getting Called Also Logcat not working Correctly

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having some trouble getting result from an Activity.
I used `startActivityForResult()`, but when I call `finish()` in the 2nd Activity, my app
crashes!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int SET_IMAGE = 2;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == SET_IMAGE){
            int position;
            position = (Integer) data.getExtras().get("CurrentImage");


            ImageView currentImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);  


            currentImage.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);

            WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
            try {
                wpm.setResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WALL PAPER SET!! :b", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    Button changeButton = new Button(this);
    Button callButton = new Button(this);

    changeButton.setText("Change Picture");
    changeButton.setTextSize(20);

    callButton.setText("Call Me ;)");
    callButton.setTextSize(20);


    iv.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.images[0]);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout Hlayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    Hlayout.addView(changeButton);
    Hlayout.addView(callButton);
    Hlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(iv);
    layout.addView(Hlayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

    iv.setLayoutParams(params);
    changeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    callButton.setLayoutParams(params);



    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LinearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(LinearLayoutParams);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



    changeButton.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(callHandler);

    setContentView(layout);

}
View.OnClickListener callHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:8307651730"));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }
};

View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), choosePic.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SET_IMAGE);

    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
`

In my 2nd activity:

```
public void finishActivity(int position){
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);


    resultIntent.putExtra("CurrentImage", position);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();


}
```

I've narrowed down the problem to `finish()`. Commenting out `finish()` makes the app run fine but when `finish()` is called the app crashes. Anyone have any idea why that is?

-edit-
onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onActivityResult Called!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == SET_IMAGE){
            int position;
            position = (Integer) data.getExtras().get("CurrentImage");

            ImageView currentImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            currentImage.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);

            WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
            try {
                wpm.setResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WALL PAPER SET!! :b", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

-edit- 
Heres my Logcat (Finally lol):

```
  thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result        ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.mrsai.profilepic/com.mrsai.profilepic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at com.mrsai.profilepic.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:34)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
 E/AndroidRuntime(667):     ... 11 more
 Sending signal. PID: 667 SIG: 9
```

***Resolved****

Fixed my problem i was referencing nothing in my xml layout because i didnt inflate it. Codemagic made me realize this :] thanks man

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: You may want to post your onActivityResult method as well.

Comment: You need to post the onActivityResult function and the log cat error for any one to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating a new instance of your `MainActivity` here

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Change your code to

```
public void finishActivity(int position){
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

    resultIntent.putExtra("CurrentImage", position);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();

}
```

When you create a new instance that way, `onCreate()` will be called instead of `onActivityResult()`. Use the empty constructor then `onActivityResult()` will be called after `setResult()`.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: To expand upon this answer- The [Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) shows that the Intent passed to `setResult(int, Intent)` contains result data; the Intent is not used to launch an Activity as the OP seems to be using it.

Comment: yeah i changed that line cause i didnt know what else to try lol umm i changed the line u told me to change but i get the same result, this brings me to my next problem cause my logcat hasnt been working recently. Right now im using my s4 to run my apps but ever since the logcat stopped working i started using the emulator but now the logcat doesnt work on the emulator either :/ could it be a problem with my drivers?

Comment: by not working i mean it doesnt give me any information when i connect a device, whether its a physical android device or an emulator. When i connect my s4 it just says: ?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected

Comment: Have you tried restarting your editor? Also, [check here](https://www.google.com/search?q=unable+to+open+log+device+android+eclipse&oq=Unable+to+open+log+device+eclipse&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i62l3.4973j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and see if any of these help with that. I don't know what's causing that

Comment: OK i tried all the stuff in those links and i could not get my logcat going again :/ there was a method by dialing a code but it didnt work for me at all. And i even tried flashing a whole no rom still cant get log cat working :/ i also get "Cant bind to local 8700 for debugger"

Comment: ok i didnt solve the problem with logcat on my physical device but it seems to be working with the emulator now so back to original problem lol i made an edit with my logcat

Comment: Post your `onActivityResult` and indicate line 34 of `MainActivitiy`

Comment: i made an edit for the onactivityresult and heres line 34:  `currentImage.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);`

Comment: You need to see what is `null` there. Looks like `currentImage`. Are you sure `imageView` is the `id` of an `ImageView` in the currently inflated `layout`?

Comment: yeah imageView is the id, and uhh could it be that images[] is returning null? cause im making a static reference to it commenting out line 34 makes it work onActivityResult is called but i need that array :/

Comment: Maybe, put a breakpoint there and see what is actually `null`

Comment: ok it says currentImage = null but it looks like i referenced it correctly

Comment: Post the xml you inflate in `setContentView()` of `MainActivity`

Comment: Ohhhh i see whats going on here lol i didnt even inflate a layout i did it all programatically so im referencing nothing cause the layout aint even set

Comment: There you go! Inflate the xml before initializing your `ImageView`